# pymysql is returning data from empty table

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

whenever running the below code the variable dictionary and therefore dictionary2 gets assigned old data.

```
import pymysql

dictionary2 = []

charSet = "utf8mb4"

cusrorType = pymysql.cursors.DictCursor

connection = pymysql.connect("localhost", "username", "password", "db", charset=charSet, cursorclass=cusrorType, autocommit=True)
c = connection.cursor()

query =("SELECT item FROM inventory WHERE user = %s AND itemVal=1 AND itemDescription = %s")
args = (str(user), str(itemDescription)
c.execute(query, args)
dictionary = c.fetchall()

for a in dictionary:
    if not a["item"] in dictionary2:
        dictionary2.append(a["item"])
```

I have truncated the table and the variables still gets assigned old data. i have tried closing all python tasks. I have also tried running it in the python shell. when run in a python shell the correct data is selected from the database.

Comment: Are you keeping this connection open continuously?  Without commits after queries the connection will fetch stale data.

Comment: yeah i am however i set autocommit to be True which commits after every execute. also wouldnt closing all python tasks also stop the connection too?